# Lightning Component not being created for certain profile

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, profile

I have a visualforce page which contains a lightning component, like so:

```
<apex:page sidebar="false">
    <apex:includeLightning />
    <script>
    $Lightning.use("c:My_App", function() {
        $Lightning.createComponent("c:My_Wrapper", 
                                   {"accId":"{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}"}, 
                                   "tmp-id", 
                                   function(cmp) {
                                       //
                                   });
    });
    </script>
    <body>
        <div>
            <div id="tmp-id" />
        </div>
    </body>
</apex:page>
```

`c:My_App` uses `extends="ltng:outApp"`:

```
<aura:application access="GLOBAL" extends="ltng:outApp" >
    <aura:dependency resource="c:My_Wrapper" />
    <aura:dependency resource="c:My_OtherWrapper" />
</aura:application>
```

Within the lightning component `c:My_Wrapper`, many calls to an apex controller are made, which does a lot of heavy lifting for the initialization of this component. As a System Administrator, this works fine. However, in another profile, these apex calls are never made.

[image: Debug logs]

The lines blocked in red can be ignored; those are unrelated. The page load happens at the lines marked with green. The apex calls are show marked with blue. As you can see, when I am a System Admin (I am the big blue rectangle, of course), these apex calls are made. As a user in the Retail profile, they are not. When this failure occurs, no apex logs or console logs are made, and the only feedback Salesforce provides is:

```
An internal server error has occurred
Error ID: 1478192347-59189 (-993347769)
```

I suspect this has something to do with access/permission for Lightning, but I don't know what permission or setting needs adjusted to fix this issue. Please point me in the right direction.

UPDATE: I have attempted several steps, one at a time, in an attempt to hit the issue with scatter-shot. None of them fixed the issue. These include:

- Giving the user Apex access to the controllers.
- Setting the controllers to `without sharing`.
- Giving the user the 'Lightning Experience User' permission and setting them up as a Lightning user

The next step I'd like to take is to try granting the 'Lightning Console User' permission, but it's grayed out and I can't seem to find the prerequisite for it.

It's also worth noting that, despite the fact that there is a `console.log` in the first line of the init of `c:My_Wrapper`, no logs are sent to console when the Retail User attempts to use this page. It seems to me that the lightning app and component are never created for this user.

SECOND UPDATE: I've created a case with Salesforce around this issue. Hopefully I'll be able to answer this question myself, if they can help me find the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I opened a case with Salesforce and they were able to help me faind the cause of my issue. The good news is, it was an easy fix. The bad news is, it's pretty obvious in retrospect.

Deep within my wrapper lies a component from an unmanaged package, which uses several custom objects contained within that package. 'Read' permissions had to be given to those custom objects in order to fix this issue.

So there was nothing wrong with Lightning, and this is definitely something I could have avoided if I had thought of the object permissions to those, but it didn't cross my mind. It's unfortunate that the error messaging isn't able to communicate this, but I'll take this as a learning opportunity.

Thanks to all who responded.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will work for you but in my case I had an aura component which worked well when logged in with a user as System Administrator but when I logged in as another user with different profile (Admin Clone: it had all the view all and modify all permissions) the aura component wouldn't respond.
So when I looked for the enabled classes for Admin Clone profile the controller class for aura component wasn't there. Once I added my controller to the same my aura component started working well.